# Inverse of triangle inequality

Tags: euclidean-geometry

If triangle inequality holds for some three sides, does it mean that there exist a triangle with this three sides ? If it is, what is the proof ?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Converse)

Comment: @MathLover Thanks